how to get dropdown values from append function
I have a function that I am using to append data elements from one dropdown option to another
The function is working properly. What I am looking for is to get the values of the second dropdown option which is an array
<select id="sel1" multiple size="5">
<option value="test1">1st test</option>
<option value="test2">2nd test</option>
<option value="test3">3rd test</option>
<option value="test4">4th test</option>
<option value="test5">5th test</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2" name = "sel2[]" multiple size="4">
<option value="dummy">Dummy</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" id="doBtn" value="do it">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="add">
 

and this is my javascript for appending elements
$('#doBtn').click(function () {
$('#sel1 option:selected').each(function () {
    $("<option/>").
    val($(this).val()).
    text($(this).text()).
    appendTo("#sel2");
});
});

when I submit it, I expect the $diag_string to have values but it returns empty
if(isset($_POST[submit]))
{
 $diag_string = implode(', ', $_POST['sel2']);

$sql ="INSERT INTO  ...... values ('...... ')";
    $qsql = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}

what has to be done to sel2[] select option to obtain values from it?

Your <select> likely needs a name attribute in order to be submitted with the form. It has nothing to do with the Javascript or php.

Options are being appended, but they're not being selected.  So when the form submits, sel2 has no selected options.
You can select them by setting a .val() on the target element after appending the options.  For example:


$('#doBtn').click(function () {
  $('#sel1 option:selected').each(function () {
    $("<option/>").
    val($(this).val()).
    text($(this).text()).
    appendTo("#sel2");
  });
  
  // set the value here
  $('#sel2').val($('#sel1').val());
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1" multiple size="5">
  <option value="test1">1st test</option>
  <option value="test2">2nd test</option>
  <option value="test3">3rd test</option>
  <option value="test4">4th test</option>
  <option value="test5">5th test</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2" name = "sel2[]" multiple size="4">
  <option value="dummy">Dummy</option>
</select>

<br>
<input type="button" id="doBtn" value="do it">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="add">



Alternatively, if you want all options to be selected, you could do that too.
